# Attribute Error when calling super class variable in sub class tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

**Python**
I am fairly new to Object Oriented Programming. I am trying to achieve the following code using the tkinter package. However I am struggling to access the self.coord variable from the super class(FirstFrame) to the subclass (ThirdFrame).

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainFrame(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = FirstFrame(container, self)
        self.frames[FirstFrame] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        frame.grid_propagate(0)

        frame1 = ThirdFrame(container, self)
        self.frames[ThirdFrame] = frame1
        frame1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

        self.show_frames(FirstFrame)
        self.show_frames(ThirdFrame)

    def show_frames(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class FirstFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, height='200', width='200', bg='green')
        self.coord = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
        lbl = tk.Label(text="You did It!")
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='n')

class ThirdFrame(FirstFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, height='500', width='100', bg='yellow')
        print("Success", self.coord)

app = MainFrame()
app.mainloop()
```

The following Attribute Error occurs when the program is executed.

```
C:\Users\lenovo\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/lenovo/IdeaProjects/Trial/tryyyrr.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/IdeaProjects/Trial/tryyyrr.py", line 48, in <module>
    app = MainFrame()
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/IdeaProjects/Trial/tryyyrr.py", line 22, in __init__
    frame1 = ThirdFrame(container, self)
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/IdeaProjects/Trial/tryyyrr.py", line 45, in __init__
    print("Success", self.coord)
AttributeError: 'ThirdFrame' object has no attribute 'coord'
```

Some guidance will really be helpful.

Comment: Self refers to that class itself, so it will cause an error, since there is no such a variable inside ThirdFrame. So you should either create a new argument in the ThirdFrame prototype, use the parent argument or use a global variable

Comment: call `super().__init__` in the ThirdFrame, instead of `tk.Frame.__init__`

Comment: I have used global variables and it works. But was curious to achieve the same this way. I'll try the super().__init__. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You called wrong super class inside `ThirdFrame.__init__()`.  It should be as below:

```py
class ThirdFrame(FirstFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        #tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, height='500', width='100', bg='yellow')
        FirstFrame.__init__(self, parent, controller)
        self.config(height=500, width=100, bg='yellow')
        print("Success", self.coord)
```